# Scroll view content inset issue on keyboardWillShow

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I've following code to adjust scroll view inset. The content inside scroll view goes below the keyboard limit as shown in screen recording - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6itwk.jpg

How do I fix this so that bottom of bottomView stick to the top of keyboard and doesn't scroll up or down?

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let kbSize = keyboardFrame.size
    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: kbSize.height, right: 0.0)

     scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
     scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using scrollView.contentInset will not fix you view above kb, it will scroll up and down as you are seeing it in your case. This solution is from Apple's code which is good to show the textView up above kb only and doesn't stick the bottom of text view above kb.

You need to move up the entire self.view by kb height.

Comment: Tx for the tips. I have manage to make it work by moving entire view up however it has some side effects. It shows up background space between keyboard and view.